# How to use the ObstacleControl module with INET framework?

Tags: veins, inet

The ObstacleControl module is implemented in veins. What I want to do is to add routing functionalities on vehicles which based on INET framework. In order to make simulations more realistic, I want to deploy various obstacles. In veins_inet subproject, VeinsInetCar extends AdhocHost from INET. My question is how to make VeinsInetCar work with veins::ObastacleControl, not inet::env... ?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `veins_inet` subproject of Veins 5.1 includes radio obstacles. Because it uses INET for simulating radio communication, it relies on INET functionalities for modeling radio obstacles.